# mutate_at conditioning on different variables dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to achieve something like the following with dplyr mutate_at but so far failed. I want to replace rows inside a variable based on the value of another variable with a different suffix.

```
df %>% mutate(a_1 = ifelse(a_2 == 1, 0, a_1),
                  b_1 = ifelse(b_2 == 1, 0, b_1))
```

I am just curios how to use different variables inside the `mutate_at` funs.

With `gather()` I can achieve my purpose but it seems like too many lines of code.

Example Input

```
   a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2
1   3   0   5   0
2   4   1   6   1
```

Expected Output

```
   a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2
1   3   0   5   0
2   0   1   0   1
```

This is just a simple illustration.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show sample data and expected output?

Comment: Use `df %>% mutate_at(vars(a_1, b_1), funs(replace(., .==1, 0)))`

Comment: Thanks akrun. This I know how to do. What I want is to condition a_1 on the values of a_2 and b_1 on b_2. Is there a easy way to do this with mutate_at?